# How do I hide all windows except the top one (like in Mac OS X)?

Tags: gnome, window-management

Is there a way to hide all other windows except the one in the foreground (besides manually hiding them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Here is the easy way I do it.

Download and install:
http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Then start **ubuntu-tweak** from the menu:

*applications->system tools->ubuntu tweak*

then go to *Compiz Settings*:

[image: Compiz Settings]

Click the install simple settings and apply. Then you see that image of your desktop with the 4 drop down menus. There you can choose different type of options to happen to the windows when you move your mouse to that corner of the screen.